# How to forward remote addr of client to backend server in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx as a load balancer for my web application.

My request flow will be like : User --> Nginx(Back end) --> Nginx(Front end) --> Tomcat Servers.

I'm trying to get the client IP address with "request.getRemoteAddr()" in my Java application. However I'm getting the front end Nginx IP as the remote address.

I tried the real IP solution and header overwrite, none of them seems to work.

My Nginx conf:

```
set_real_ip_from 10.44.0.0;
real_ip_header CLIENT-REAL-IP;

upstream backend {
        server xxxxxx:port;
        server yyyyyy:port;

}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name xxxxxx;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_read_timeout 100;
        }
}
```

The backend Nginx passes the client IP in custom header- CLIENT-REAL-IP to front end Nginx. I can see the CLIENT-REAL-IP address in the front end Nginx log.

I am able to set the client IP in some other custom header and access it in my Java application.
But I want the correct client IP in remote_addr.

As per my understanding the mentioned real_ip_header should be set as remote_address.

Nginx version: nginx/1.18.0

Can someone please help?

Comment: You need to pass the remote address to the upstream server. This is often achieved using the `X-Forwarded-For` header. For example: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`
I've tried your solution , but it not fixed my issue. As per nginx doc 

```proxy_add_x_forwarded_for - the “X-Forwarded-For” client request header field with the $remote_addr variable appended to it, separated by a comma. If the “X-Forwarded-For” field is not present in the client request header, the $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for variable is equal to the $remote_addr variable.```

It just appends the remote_addr to X-Forwarded-For header, it doesn't preserve the client IP in remote_addr.

Comment: Make up your own header, then.

Comment: One of the libraries we have bundled is using  "request.getRemoteAddr()", So I can't use custom headers.